# Build iOS Framework with dependency of other frameworks

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I am building iOS Framework that depends on another 3 frameworks. To do that in my Framework project I installed pods and the structure looks like this now:

[image]

Ok so far so good. I created podspec and added the nessecery dependecies such as AFNetworking, Socket Rocket and pjsip. When I run pod install cheryz I get in my test project this structure:

[image]

When I compile the Test project I got error:

[image]

I understand why this is happening. Because on the framework project I use workspace and the imports are made `<SocketRocket/SRWebRocket>` but on my Test projet where I install my framework with the dependencies I will need to write something like `import "SRWebRocket.h"` to work.

How I can fix this. I guess I am doing wrong the framework project. It should not be with workspace and additional frameworks such as AFNetworking in pod project ? 
Also when I execute pod spec lint I get error on building. I guess this is the reason

Comment: Perhaps add `use_frameworks!` to the Podfile

Comment: Actually it's the opposite, I removed use_frameworks! and it starts working